# New type for the deprecated grocery_or_supermarket type in google-places-API

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

Looks like google has deprecated a bunch of place types from their places API:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types
"The following types are deprecated, and will continue to be supported until February 16, 2017: establishment, finance, food, general_contractor, grocery_or_supermarket, health, place_of_worship."

I wasn't able to figure out what the new replacement types would be. "food" and "store" are too generic for a grocery related store.

Additionally, the documentation states that these types are deprecated only for the query API. The place-details results "may" still contain them.

A workaround I can implement is to fetch the places using a more generic type (e.g., store), and then filter on my end.. not ideal, but out of ideas. However, this also means that I'll rely on the more granular type (e.g., grocery_or_supermarket) to be mentioned in the response.

Can someone pls comment or share ideas on this issue? (did any of you have to deal with this? would be great if you can share your thoughts)

Thanks

Comment: Indeed grocery_or_supermarket can hardly be trusted due to deprecation but in my humble opinion, *convenience_store* still returns result as expected from grocery_or_supermarket, have a real close look at all the options listed in https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types#table1

Answer (score 0):

Use Foursquare API for this data instead of Google, just get a Foursquare API key, check the API how to use details online and that should provide the data your need.